About convex set in normed vector spaces.
I'm trying to prove the following statement: Let E be a normed vector space. If $C \subset E$ is a convex subset, then $Int(C)$ is also convex.
First, let me explain the notations I'm using: $B(x,r)$ stands for the open ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$, $Int(C)$ stands for the set of all interior points of the set $C$, and $||\cdot||$ is the norm defined on the vector space $E$.
Alright, this is what I have so far:
Let $x, y \in Int(C)$. By definition, there exist $r_1 > 0$ and $r_2 > 0$ such that $B(x, r_1), B(y, r_2) \subset C$. Since $C$ is convex, for each pair of elements in $C$, the line segment connecting those elements lies in $C$. This allows us to say that:
$tB(x,r_1)+(1-t)B(y,r_2)\subset C$, $\forall t\in[0,1]$.
My first question is:


Is it sufficient to show that $B(tx + (1-t)y, t(r_1 + r_2)) \subset C$? Is that correct?


My intuition tells me that it is sufficient to show (1) because (1) means that for each pair of elements in $C$, there exists an open ball containing the line segment connecting the pair of points together.
Now, note that $tB(x, r_1)=\{tz:z \in B(x,r_1)\}$, and it is quite easy to show that $tB(x,r_1)=B(tx,tr_1)$. In fact,
$$w\in tB(x,r_1) \Leftrightarrow w=tz, z\in B(x,r_1)\Leftrightarrow ||x-z||<r_1 \Leftrightarrow ||tx-w||<tr_1\Leftrightarrow w\in B(tx,tr_1)$$
My second question is:


Do I also have to show that $B(x,r_1)+B(y,r_2)=B(x+y,r_1+r_2)$? Is that correct?


It is easy to show one direction of this equality. In fact, given $w\in B(x,r_1)+B(y,r_2)$, there exist $u\in B(x,r_1)$ and $v\in B(y,r_2)$ such that $w=u+v$. This tells us:
$$||(x+y)-(u+v)||=||(x-u)+(y-v)||\leq ||x-u||+||y-v||<r_1+r_2$$
and we conclude that $w \in B(x + y, r_1 + r_2)$. However, I haven't been able to prove the converse.
And my third and final question is:


Once I have (1) and (2) proved, are we done?
I mean, is proving (1) and (2) enough to conclude the statement?


I really need help with this, and I would really appreciate it.
Thank you.

I think you are complicating this a bit more than what is needed. The statement in (1) also is not expected: why would the radius be $t(r_1+r_2)$?
You want to show that $\mathrm{int}(C)$ is convex. Let $x,y\in\mathrm{int}(C)$ be two points; so we need to show that, for any $t\in[0,1]$, $tx+(1-t)y\in\mathrm{int}(C)$. So let $t\in[0,1]$. To show that $tx+(1-t)y\in\mathrm{int}(C)$, we need to find some $r>0$ so that $B(tx+(1-t)y, r)\subset C$. Let's do that.
Since $x,y\in\mathrm{int}(C)$, there are $r_x,r_y>0$ with $B(x,r_x) \subset C$ and $B(y,r_y)\subset C$. Set $r:= \min\{r_x,r_y\}>0$. We claim that $B(tx+(1-t)y, r) \subset C$. We prove this claim: let $z$ be a vector with $\|z-(tx+(1-t)y)\|<r$, and set $w:=z-(tx+(1-t)y)$. Set $w_x:=w+x$ and $w_y:=w+y$. Then $\|x-w_x\|=\|w\|<r\le r_x$ and $\|y-w_y\|=\|w\|<r\le r_y$, so $w_x\in B(x,r)$ and $w_y\in B(y,r)$. We have that
$$t \cdot w_x + (1-t)\cdot w_y = tw+tx+(1-t)w+(1-t)y=w+tx+(1-t)y=z.$$
Since $w_x,w_y\in C$ and $C$ is convex, $z=tw_x+(1-t)w_y\in C$. This proves the claim.
Let me explain the idea. I drew two circles, one with a big radius and one with small, and I joined the centers (these are $x,y$). I took a point on the segment joining the centers (this is $tx+(1-t)y$) and I asked myself: for which radii can I conclude with certainty that the ball centered there with that radius is covered by line segments where the endpoints lie inside the two initial circles$^{(*)}$? you will notice that if $tx+(1-t)y$ is veery close to the center of the circle with the small radius, your radius will also need to be quite small (in the euclidean plane with the two norm, it's okay if it is a little bigger, but this is another problem of geometric nature). In particular, taking the radius equal to the smaller one suffices.
$^{(*)}$: Covering this ball with such segments ensures that the ball is contained in $C$, due to convexity.
The proof above is just a formal way of saying what I just described.
As for (2), this is correct, but as you see above it is not really needed. For completeness let me provide a proof for (2) as well. It suffices to show that $B(x,r+r')=B(x,r)+B(0,r')$. Then we can write $B(x+y,r+r')=B(x+y,r)+B(0,r')=B(x,r)+y+B(0,r')=B(x,r)+B(y,r')$.
Let us show this statement then. Take $z\in B(x,r+r')$. If $\|z-x\|<r'$, then $z=x+(z-x)\in B(x,r)+B(0,r')$ and there is nothing to show. So we may assume that $\|z-x\| \ge r'$. Note that for any $t\in[0,1]$ we have
$$z  = t(z-x) + (1-t)z+tx \quad (\star).$$
Let $\varepsilon>0$ to be specified soon. Taking $t=\frac{r'}{\|z-x\|+\varepsilon}\in[0,1]$ we have that $z':=t(z-x)$ has norm $<r'$, so $z'\in B(0,r')$ and if $z'':=(1-t)z+tx$, we have that
$$\|x-z''\|=(1-t)\cdot\|z-x\|=\|z-x\|-r'\frac{\|z-x\|}{\|z-x\|+\varepsilon}.$$
Since $\|z-x\|<r+r'$, we have that
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\bigg(\|z-x\|-r'\frac{\|z-x\|}{\|z-x\|+\varepsilon}\bigg)=\|z-x\|-r'<r$$,
so there is some small $\varepsilon_0>0$ so that $\|z-x\|-r'\frac{\|z-x\|}{\|z-x\|+\varepsilon_0} <r$. Taking $\varepsilon=\varepsilon_0$ above, we see that $\|x-z''\|<r$, whence $z''\in B(x,r)$. By $(\star)$, $z=z'+z''$ and we are done.

Let me see if I got this right: when you took $z\in B(tx+(1-t)y, r)$, you determined a pair of points in terms of $z$ (namely $w_x$ and $w_x$, each one inside the 2 balls previously defined). It is clear that all 3 points lie in the same line, and since $C$ is  convex, this line must lie inside $C$. Thus $B(tx+(1-t)y,r)$ is inside of C and we conclude that $int(C)$ is convex.
I'm just not sure about the role of $w$. Is it to make sure that the points $w_x$ and $w_y$ are inside each ball?

@JoelMarques I just used $w$ to denote the "defect", i.e. how far $z$ is from the center $tx+(1-t)y$. Then I "defected" the centers $x$ and $y$ by the same thing (as a vector, i.e.  both in direction and length if we are in a Euclidean space), thats why we considered $w+x$ and $w+y$.

Thank you so much for your help!
